# How to add hidden control in OpenUI5?

Tags: hidden-field, sapui5

I would like to add a hidden control in Open UI5 framework.Can any one help me on this?

Comment: What is a *hidden control* exactly? Is it in the DOM but just not visible?
 Or is it not even in the DOM? When exactly do you want to *hide* it? What's the context? What do you actually want to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

You can hide any SAPUI5 control using the `property`

```
visible:false //by default it will be true
```

OR use method `setVisible(false);`

[sample is here](http://jsbin.com/wuxecajacu/edit?html,output)